# send mouse/keyboard inputs to active/inactive windows

Tags: python, automation, mouse, pynput

I use python and pynput to automate my mouse.
But obviously, it is impossible to use the computer at the same time for other things. So I'm looking for a solution to either automate a "second" virtual mouse or to just send mouse clicks to a specific window (active or inactive) on Windows 10 without actually using the real mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyautogui to automate keyboard and mouse actions; but if you are using the keyboard and mouse it will interfere with these commands. the same could be said about adding another mouse; it doesn't add a second OS pointer; it only creates another (at times conflicting) control over that pointer.